# I am trying to use the index function in Excel VBA in order to find an ID in one table and insert that ID into another table

Tags: excel, vba

Right now, I have 2 tables, "Initial Status" and "Weekly Upload". I would like to have my "Weekly Upload" update my initial using VBA. In addition to the title, If the ID does not exist in the table "Initial Status", I would like to add it along with the data. If it does exist I would just like to update the status but not have duplicate IDs.

Right now I have a code that copies and pastes data from one table to another in the correct location but I can only get it to work if I use a fixed value. I am trying to use an Index function (right after my if statement) to check if the ID exists or not but I cannot get the right syntax.

I am new to VBA and any insight or suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

I have tried messing around with my Index Match but I cannot get it to work.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
a = Worksheets("weekly upload").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox (a)
For i = 2 To a
    If Worksheets("weekly upload").Cells(i, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Initial Status").Range("A2:A7")) Then
        Worksheets("weekly upload").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("initial status").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Initial Status").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("initial status").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("weekly upload").Activate

    End If

Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("weekly upload").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

As of now I am also getting an error from my index saying "Compile error: Argument not Optional"

Comment: You are not providing a relative row number for the range.

Comment: Index function takes two arguments, does it not? You're only passing a range. You need to pass the value that you're searching for within that range, also.

Comment: Thank you! But how would I search for this with the value that I am looking for being different for every instance in the for loop? Would I use an index match?

Comment: what's the value that you're looking for? How is that value determined by the loop/iteration?

Comment: Well because it is looping through every row in Column A in my table so the value that it is searching for in my other table is also changing. I'm sorry if I am not explaining that greatly I am new to VBA and Index Match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to modify your code as per my understanding of the objective. Used [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) method to search for ID.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim StRow As Long, LastRow As Long, IntLastRow As Long, Id As Variant
Dim IdRng As Range, c As Range
Dim WsInt As Worksheet, WsWeek As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, Rw As Long

Set WsInt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Initial Status")
Set WsWeek = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("weekly upload")
StRow = 2
LastRow = WsWeek.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = StRow To LastRow
    'Assumed Id is in Column A of Sheet weekly upload
    Id = WsWeek.Cells(i, 1).Value
    IntLastRow = WsInt.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set IdRng = WsInt.Range(WsInt.Range("A2"), WsInt.Range("A" & IntLastRow))
    'Search for Id in Sheet Initial Status column A
    Set c = IdRng.Find(What:=Id, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If c Is Nothing Then
        'If ID not found copy to lastrow+1
        Rw = IntLastRow + 1
        Else
        'If ID found copy to that row
        Rw = c.Row
        End If
    WsWeek.Rows(i).Copy WsInt.Rows(Rw)
    Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

For tracking changes may use something like this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim StRow As Long, LastRow As Long, IntLastRow As Long, Id As Variant
Dim IdRng As Range, c As Range
Dim WsInt As Worksheet, WsWeek As Worksheet, WsTrack As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, Rw As Long
Dim LastCol As Long, j As Long, OldVal As Variant, NewVal As Variant

Set WsInt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Initial Status")
Set WsWeek = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("weekly upload")
Set WsTrack = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Track")
StRow = 2
LastRow = WsWeek.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = StRow To LastRow
    'Assumed Id is in Column A of Sheet weekly upload
    Id = WsWeek.Cells(i, 1).Value
    IntLastRow = WsInt.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set IdRng = WsInt.Range(WsInt.Range("A2"), WsInt.Range("A" & IntLastRow))
    LastCol = WsWeek.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'Search for Id in Sheet Initial Status column A
    Set c = IdRng.Find(What:=Id, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If c Is Nothing Then
        'If ID not found copy to lastrow+1
        Rw = IntLastRow + 1
        Else
        'If ID found copy to that row
        Rw = c.Row
        End If

        For j = 1 To LastCol
        OldVal = WsInt.Cells(Rw, j).Value
        NewVal = WsWeek.Cells(i, j).Value
        WsInt.Cells(Rw, j).Value = NewVal
        WsTrack.Cells(Rw, j).Value = IIf(j = 1, "", OldVal & "->") & NewVal
        Next j
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: WOW! That is amazing, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help and time Ahmed. But  if I wanted to keep a change log and keep track of the changes that were made in a separate excel document would this be possible?

Comment: Yes of course! So the change log would be a running list of all the changes made per ID. So lets say if one week my ID 3 has a status of 30 days late then the next week it is updated to 60. My Recent table would only show 60 but I would to insert changes into a change table to show *ID* **3** *Status* **30** and *ID* **3** *Status* **60**. I hope I am describing this correctly and please let me know if you would like me to link an example for better clarification. Thank you once again for your help Ahmed :)

Comment: Additionally, one idea that I had in mind was copying and pasting the data to another sheet before updating my table with the VBA that you provided me with. This would allow me to see my most recent status and also the week before that status. Would it then be possible to create a VBA that can compare the 2 sheets and insert the differences (changes) into another sheet?

Comment: There would only be 2 columns that would be changing, the status and the date. So do you think that this would be possible through VBA?

Comment: The code provided would take care of all the data in the row.. However you  could control/limit that with a fixed value for `LastCol`.

Comment: It wouldn't have to be a fixed value because the other columns will still remain the same throughout. I would just do this if it would save time/ to avoid slow performance. I will explore options for the Track Log now! Thank you once again for your help Ahmed it is much appreciated!

Comment: Wait sorry I did not even see that you added code for the tracking! I will try that out right now.

Comment: This is almost what I am looking for but I think I explained it a little poorly. So as of now, whenever there is a change It just adds the most recent change and then states the previous change from which it came from(30 -> 60). I am trying to have a running list of all the changes. So if the ID *5*'s status goes from **30** to **60** to **90**. I would like the track sheet to show ID *5* Status **60** then in a new row ID *5* Status **90**.  I will try to tweak it in order to accomplish this but you have helped me out tremendously. Once again thank you very much for your help Ahmed!

Comment: Please specify 1) How many columns are required to be copied and 2) Which columns have Date and status. 3) if all the columns have data (values) only or it is required to copy formula also. If tracking of changes in only two fields are required than it could be done easily.